# How can I see what the default value of a visit is?

Tags: rascal

Assume I have:

```
visit(p) { 
   case ...
   default:
       println("This should not happen. All elements should be catched. Check: <x>");
};
```

How can I print out (in this case as x) what could not be matched?

I tried:

```
x:default:

\x:default:

default:x:

\default:x:
```

Tx,

Jos

Answer (score 0):

We have a library named `Traversal` that allows you to get back the context of a match. So, you can do something like this:

```
import Traversal;
import IO;

void doit() {
    m = (1:"one",2:"two",3:"three");
    bottom-up visit(m) {
        case int n : println("<n> is an int");
        default: {
            tc = getTraversalContext();
            println("Context is: <tc>");
            println("<tc[0]> is not an int");
            if (str s := tc[0]) {
                println("<s> is a string");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`tc` is then a list of all the nodes back to the top of the term -- in this case, it will just be the current value, like `"three"`, and the entire value of map `m` (or the entire map, which will also be a match for the default case). If you had something structured as a tree, such as terms formed using ADTs or nodes, you would get all the intervening structure from the point of the match back to the top (which would be the entire term).

For some reason, though, `default` is matching the same term multiple times. I've filed this as bug report https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues/731 on GitHub.

Comment: Mark, I believe we do not support default for the visit truly because substitution would be unsafe

Comment: Agreed, the type would be problematic if nothing else. I don't use default in visits, only in switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this idiom:

```
visit(x) {
  case ...
  case ...
  case value x: throw "default case should not happen <x>";
}
```

The value pattern will catch everything but only after the others are tried.

Comment: The other answer by Mark will give you more context information which is useful as well. But i usually start with this.

Comment: Agreed, I guess I was trying to do it while sticking with default, but this would obviously be easier (unless you need the traversal context anyway).